# How to show k2 items in k2 content module in 3 columns?

Tags: php, joomla, k2

Joomla k2 component is power Joomla content system. k2 has a module that's called k2 content module and you can override the layout template of it.

I had this code for my k2 content module, this template file shows k2 items in 2 columns with even and odd classes and extra fields in it.

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// includes placehold
 $yt_temp = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate();
 include (JPATH_BASE . '/templates/'.$yt_temp.'/includes/placehold.php');

  ?>

<div id="k2ModuleBox<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="k2ItemsBlock<?php 
if($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) echo ' '.$params-
>get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">

<?php if($params->get('itemPreText')): ?>
<p class="modulePretext"><?php echo $params->get('itemPreText'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(count($items)): ?>
<ul class="product">
<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$item):  ?>
<li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; if(count($items)==$key+1) 
echo ' lastItem'; ?>">

  <?php if($params->get('itemImage') || $params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>

      <?php if($params->get('itemImage')): ?>
     <div class="product-image">   
                   <img src="<?php echo $item->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
  K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($item->title); ?>" />
          </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
     <div class="main">
    <?php if($params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
    <p class="moduleItemTitle"><?php echo $item->title; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>  
    <?php if($params->get('itemIntroText')): ?>
    <div class="introtext">
        <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
                  <!-- end main-->

  <?php if($params->get('itemExtraFields') && count($item->extra_fields)): ?
   >
  <div class="moduleItemExtraFields-energi">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($item->extra_fields as $extraField): ?>
                <?php if($extraField->value != ''): ?>
                <li class="type<?php echo ucfirst($extraField->type); ?> 
    group2">
                    <?php if($extraField->type == 'header'): ?>
                    <h4 class="moduleItemExtraFieldsHeader"><?php echo 
    $extraField->name; ?></h4>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsLabel"><?php echo 
    $extraField->name; ?></span>
                    <span class="moduleItemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo 
    $extraField->value; ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="clr"></div>
  </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   <li class="clearList"></li>
  </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
```

**I would like to show my articles in 3 columns with extra fields.**

How to do this? If it's possible, help me to do it.
Thanks for your attention.